# Why Z-buffer cannot be read with glReadPixel()?

Tags: c++, opengl

I am using an opengl rendering program to do some simulation. Unfortunately, the model redering code is not availabe. What I'm doing is first loading and rendering a model with this program, and the model can be selected and translated, then trying to get the fragment information including z-buffer and normal vector for further simulation. But when I use glReadPixel() to get z-buffer, all the values are 1.0, even the fragment of the model area. I know it should be between 0.0 and 1.0.

Because I don't know how the model is rendered in the program, so anyone could help what the problem is and in which rendering case the z-buffer cannot be read correctly.

Comment: Are you able / willing to use FBOs?

Comment: Can you include at least a few lines of code, including the actual call to `glReadPixels (...)`? If you do not need the data on the CPU, but can structure your simulation to use a depth texture lookup in shaders then an FBO is going to be much more efficient.

Comment: But the rendering code is not programmed by myself, and I don't know if the program is using FBO or just opengl. The following is my z-buffer reading code: \nint iSize = m_winWidth*m_winHeight;
float* zbf = new float[iSize];
glReadPixels(0,0,m_winWidth,m_winHeight,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT,zbf);
//save to file
FILE* pf = fopen("e:\\ljz\\proe\\zbf.dat", "w");
for (int j=0; j<m_winHeight; j++)
{
 for (int k=0; k<m_winWidth; k++)
 {
  fprintf(pf, "%.4f\t", zbf[j*m_winWidth+k]);
 }
 fprintf(pf, "\n");
}
fclose(pf);

Answer (score 1):

My guess: You could be doing everything right but somewhere in your inherited code the depth buffer gets cleared or lost. For example the model rendering code could render its stuff to a FBO and then only pass on the color attachment.

Comment: But if the depth buffer is cleared or lost, how to select items in the scene. I know that z-buffer is essential data for selecting. Am I right?

Comment: @user3101779: No, the purpose of the z buffer is not for selecting things. The purpose of the z buffer is hidden surface removal, i.e. if you're rendering a triangle that's "behind" another triangle, that only those parts not occluded are visible. **OpenGL is not a scene graph**. OpenGL's purpose is not scene management. *You should not use OpenGL for selecting (because it's rather inefficient). Instead you should implement ray intersection picking which is much more efficient if done properly; but that's not done using OpenGL.

Comment: @user3101779: In your case you like can get information about the location of the model within the scene by other means. Look for things like "transformation matrices" and "bounding boxes" in the foreign code's part. If everything fails you could try to intercept the OpenGL calls made to render the model and work from there.

Comment: I don't mean to do picking myself. I mean in the program I'm working with, picking should be done with opengl and in which z-buffer should be used as when picking, if there are more than one items at the cursor location, z-buffer should be used to indicate which item should be picked. But I'm not sure if picking is done in the program as what you said. And in your method, is z-buffer necessary for picking? As to "transformation matrices", I know Unproject function is what I need, but one of the necessary parameter for Unproject is z-buffer.

Comment: @user3101779: It's a common misconception that you require the depth buffer value for unprojecting. You can simply call gluUnProject twice with winZ being 0 and 1, giving you two points in the view space. Those form a ray, which you can then use for ray-intersection based picking. *You do not need, and you should not use the depth buffer for selection operations!*

Comment: Thanks for the help. But what I need is the depth value of a specific pixel on the screen, not the picking method. Can we get the depth value with what you said twice calling of gluUnProject?

Comment: @user3101779: So why do you need the specific depth value of the pixel under the mouse? To me it sounds like you're thinkging like "so if I unproject that specific depth value I can unproject into specific x,y,z coordinates and from the determine which object was clicked on." If it's something like this: **STOP!** A coordinate obtained this way will suffer from the limited precision of the depth buffer **and** related to points on the "surface" of the object. For selection however you want to compare with a bounding volume, like a bounding sphere or a (axis aligned) bounding box.

Comment: @user3101779: Bounding volumes however should be arranged in a spatial subdivision data structure. And intersecting rays can be implemented very efficiently on octrees and Kd-trees; points are efficient to look up as well, but for a points you always have to compare all three components against all dimensions in the tree. Rays however have their endpoints on the bounds of the tree volume, so in average it takes less operations to intersect a ray into an octree or Kd tree, if done right.